# Routing my Node.js application with a 'routes' object throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to make a chat application by following along a udemy node.js course. It returns. My code can be [found here](https://github.com/RoadToCode822/catchat)

```
return h.routes(routes);
             ^
TypeError: h.routes is not a function
```

Not sure how to fix this. I followed everything the instructor asked me to do. I did it from scratch three times thinking I might have had a type somewhere but still the same error at the same point.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
Here's the code from catchat/app/routes/index.js

```
'use strict';
const h = require('../helpers');

module.exports = () => {
    let routes = {
        'get': {
            '/': (req, res, next) => {
                res.render('login');
            },
            '/rooms': (req, res, next) => {
                res.render('rooms');
            },
            '/chat': (req, res, next) => {
                res.render('chatroom');
            }
        },
        'post': {

        }
    }

    return h.routes(routes);
}
```

Comment: Per the guidelines here at Stack Overflow, more of the relevant code should be pasted directly into your question so people can see what's wrong without relying on an external resource.

Comment: The problem has been solved but thank you, i'll remember for next time

Comment: You should still put the relevant code in your question.  The point of that guideline is that off-site links tend to get changed or disappear rendering this question of little use going forward and an important aspect of this site is as a searchable reference for future coders.  Any code needed to answer the question should be pasted into the question even though you already have an answer.

Comment: is that okay? or should i add more

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your helpers module https://github.com/RoadToCode822/catchat/blob/master/app/helpers/index.js you're exporting `{ routes }`, but you're trying to use it in your routes module as if it was exported as `{ routes: routes }`